# Android softkeyboard hiding the login button

Tags: android, scroll, soft-keyboard

In my application login screen has username , password and login button , if i enter the username the soft keyboard appears and it hides the Login button , i am using scroll view with linear layout ,

i have tried so far is . `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest file and also tried with adjustpan , both not working

scrool view gave fillviewport =  true.

> here is my layout code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f2f2f4"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.xyz.login.ActivityLogin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#f2f2f4"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_username"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#3b3b3b"
        android:textColorHint="#5c5c5c" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#3b3b3b"
        android:textColorHint="#5c5c5c"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember_me"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box_btn_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/remember_me"
        android:textColor="#282828" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/remember_me"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/attempts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/need_help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/attempts"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/need_help_"
        android:textColor="#332f61" />
</LinearLayout>
```

can you give me suggestion

Comment: post the layout file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ScrollView, I think it prevents the `adjustResize` to work as you intend.

From https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html :

> For example, to ensure that the system resizes your layout to the available space—which ensures that all of your layout content is accessible (even though it probably requires scrolling)—use "adjustResize":

Comment: Adjust resize just makes sure the layout is small enough for the edit text to be visible, it won't help with the login button